# How to design Student QRcode meal card system using Django

Tags: python, django

Hello Django developers,
I want to build student cafeteria system using QRcode scanner.
Here is how it should work.
Student scann there meal card, then the system displays student info and also it should mark served. Then the system count the number of served students.
The system should ignore or show red labeled text if there is rescanning.

So here i who can help me what things i have to consider to get the django model.

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  This site is not a place to get free coding or software design work, nor is it a place to get tutoring.  What you're asking is WAY too broad a question for this site. Have you learned to use Django yet?  Have you been through one or two tutorials on how to build sites with it?  Until you've done these things and then have started into writing the cafeteria system and are having problems, this site is not the place to look for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pypi package: [qrcode](https://pypi.org/project/qrcode/)

```
from django.db.models.signals import pre_save
import qrcode
from django.core.files import File
from io import BytesIO

class Qrcode(models.Model):
    qrcode = models.ImageField(upload_to="images/", blank=True)

def pre_save_qrcode(sender, instance, *args, **kwargs):
    qr = qrcode.QRCode(
        version=15,
        error_correction=qrcode.constants.ERROR_CORRECT_H,
        box_size=4,
        border=2,
    )
    qr_code_data = f'{instance.data_you_want_to_put.like s.id_card_no}'
    qr.add_data(qr_code_data)
    qr.best_fit(1)
    qr.make(fit=False)
    img = qr.make_image(fill_color="black", back_color="white")
    file_name = 'qr-' + instance.id_card_no + '.png'
    buffer = BytesIO()
    img.save(buffer, 'PNG')
    instance.qrcode.delete(save=False)  # delete previous image from media folder
    instance.qrcode.save(file_name, File(buffer), save=False)
    img.close()


pre_save.connect(pre_save_qrcode, sender=Qrcode)
```

Here we are using **pre_save** signal before the model save. Note: **version, box_size, border** are very important here. box_size and border will increase & decrease size the qr code image for fit.